# OWL type inference with a restriction

Tags: type-inference, ontology, owl, restriction, protege4

I am studying the notion of OWL restrictions with Protege 4 using FaCT++ and a trivial ontology. Suppose I have an individual `foo` of class `Something`:

```
:Something a owl:Class.
:foo a :Something, owl:NamedIndividual.
```

and another class defined from a restriction on the `hasBar` property:

```
:hasBar a owl:ObjectProperty.
:SomethingElse owl:equivalentClass [a owl:Restriction;
                                    owl:onProperty :hasBar;
                                    owl:allValuesFrom :Something].
```

If I assert that:

```
:x :hasBar :foo.
```

why can't I infer from it that `x` is a `SomethingElse` (via the fact that `foo` is a `Something`)? The only way I can make it work is if the `range` of `hasBar` is defined:

```
:hasBar a owl:ObjectProperty;
        rdfs:range :Something.
```

But I'd like to avoid that, because it puts a constraint on what can be the subject of `hasBar` (which causes me further trouble).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is simpler to reason over real examples, let's consider the following knowledge base:

```
:eats rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty .

:Vegetable rdf:type owl:Class ;
       rdfs:subClassOf owl:Thing .

:Vegetarian rdf:type owl:Class ;
        owl:equivalentClass [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                              owl:onProperty :eats ;
                              owl:allValuesFrom :Vegetable
                            ] .

:Carrot rdf:type :Vegetable ,
             owl:NamedIndividual .

:John rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual , owl:Thing ;
      :eats :carrot .
```

You have some equivalences with your example: `hasBar` is `eats`, `Vegetarian` is `SomethingElse`, `Vegetable` is `Something`, `foo` is `carrot` and finally `x` is `John`.

Now you would like to infer that `John` is a `Vegetarian` (= `x` is `SomethingElse`).

It makes sense that it doesn't work with an `owl:allValuesFrom`. What you are saying here is that *all instances of vegetarian, if they have a property, they must have Vegetable in range.* So from that you could deduce that `carrot` is a vegetable for example, assuming you would know that John is a vegetarian in the first place.

It makes sense in natural language too: In your ontology you only know that John eats a carrot, this doesn't automatically make him a vegetarian (non-vegetarian people eat also carrots).

You could use a `owl:someValuesFrom` instead of a `owl:allValuesFrom`. This way, you would define every vegetarian has someone that eats some vegetable. In this case if we know that John eats a carrot, therefore he would be classified as vegetarian by the reasoner, based on your definition of the concept *vegetarian*.

Universal (`allValuesFrom`) and existential (`someValuesFrom`) restrictions are complicated to understand, there is often no right or wrong solution, it mostly depends to what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I had already figured out that using `owl:someValuesFrom` works better in that case, but this explains nicely why. Even though my intuition easily accepts your natural language interpretation, I still find that in a sense, you could argue that given all you know about the world (namely that `John` `eats` a `Carrot`, which is a `Vegetable`), the condition for being in the `owl:allValuesFrom` version of the `Vegetarian` restriction are thus fully satisfied. But I guess this is related to the open/closed world notion, which I don't fully grok yet.

Comment: yeah, restrictions are super tricky, but the reasoner helps you out as you have seen, to better understand the semantics of OWL. Good luck!