# How to define and apply a property to all instances of a given class?

Tags: owl, protege

I'm working on a test ontology on flight reservation. I have a problem defining an axiom on a part of my ontology.

I have three classes, called *Person*, *VIPPerson* and *NormalPerson* and a property *is_after* to indicate that a person has to go after an other one.

What I want to say is that each instance of *NormalPerson* has to be related to each instance of *VIPPerson* by the relation *is_after*. Is it possible to express this axiom in a class definition?

Feel free to format or retitle my message if you want to.

Comment: I found another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21512765/how-to-relate-each-instance-of-class-with-each-instance-of-another-class?rq=1). I used rolification and it worked.